# Spring - How to load a new hierarchical context?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, java-ee-6

Has anyone tried loading multiple hierarchical contexts (parent/child) using Spring?

Could you explain how to do that as I could not locate enough documentation on this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In what sort of application? A webapp with servlets, or a standalone app?

Comment: A webapp with servlets.. I basically want to bring up a separate context of a library such that my web app is able to use beans from it but the library should not inject my same named beans into its own class files.

Comment: People any idea on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Spring classes [ContextLoaderListener](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/context/ContextLoaderListener.html) and [ContextLoader](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/context/ContextLoader.html) perform the task of initializing the webapp's application context, as well as optionally associating another application context as the parent.

In particular, the [loadParentContext()](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/context/ContextLoader.html#loadParentContext%28javax.servlet.ServletContext%29) method by default uses [ContextSingletonbeanFactoryLocator](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/context/access/ContextSingletonBeanFactoryLocator.html) to try and find the webapp's parent context, but if that's not suitable then you can subclass ContextLoader (and ContextLoaderListener) to programmatically locate your library's appcontext.

Comment: Skaffman, do we have something for non-webapps also?
And secondly, could you please point me to sample web.xml where hierarchy is being set?

Answer (score 2):

Seems like I have figured out how to do this.. (thanks to '**skaffman**' for helping)

In the web.xml define a context param `locatorFactorySelector` and set it's value to parent context's beans.xml file. By default, the search is for classpath*:beanRefContext.xml file.

Thats it !

Now I need to see how to make my JUnits load the parent context. Should be simple - by just placing the `beanRefContext.xml` file in the same directory but lets see.

Answer (score 1):

Create your application context with the 3rd party application context as a parent. That way the 3rd party app context will not be able to see your beans but your application context will be able to see the beans created by the 3rd party library (it's parent factory).

Comment: Whatever u said is fine. But I need some usage on how to do that. What configurations are required etc. ("How" is important here )